# recv() operation cannot terminate on gracefully closed socket

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock, recv

Simplified version of my client/server code:

```
/*------CLIENT CODE------*/
SOCKET server_socket;
...
result = send(server_socket, buffer, ...); //error handling after send
shutdown(server_socket, SD_SEND);
log.("data sent successfully, bytes: %d, waiting for response", buffer.size());
result = recv(server_socket, ...); //wait for response

/*------SERVER CODE------*/
SOCKET client_socket; 
... // client_socket I/O mode is initialized to non-blocking

for(int retry_num = 0;;)
{
    result = recv(client_socket, ...);
    if(result == 0)
    {
        log.("connection gracefully closed by client");
        break;
    }
    else if(result > 0)
    {
        log("received %d bytes", result);
        //add received chunk to buffer and loop again
    }
    else // error occured
    {
        switch(WSAGetLastError())
        {
            case WSAEWOULDBLOCK: 
                if (++retryNumber == MAX_RETRY_NUMBER) //MAX_RETRY_NUMBER = 10
                {
                    log.("timeout reached on recv()"); 
                    throw ...
                }
                log.("socket would block, retrying after short timeout");
                sleep(DELAY); //about 50 milliseconds
                break;
            ...
        }
    
    }
}
result = send(client_socket, ...); //send response
```

Sample logs from proper flow:

> CLIENT: data sent successfully, bytes: 150, waiting for response
>
> SERVER: received 150 bytes
>
> SERVER: connection gracefully closed by client

Sometimes flow is crashing due to timeout on server side, logs form bad flow:

> CLIENT: data sent successfully, bytes: 150, waiting for response
>
> SERVER: received 150 bytes
>
> SERVER: socket would block, retrying after short timeout
>
> ... above log occurs MAX_RETRY_NUMBER - 1 more times
>
> SERVER: timeout reached on recv()

It seems that sometimes server is unable to receive **FIN** signal sent by client during *shutdown()* method.

Client application is triggered by Task Scheduler just after Windows boot.

Bad case represents 5-10% of all cases and **it is not reproducible** when cases are performed on working Windows, it only occurs when application is triggered just after Windows boot.

What can cause such a strange behavior? Maybe Winsock is sometimes faulty/busy after Windows boot?

Comment: Windows can complete the boot process and let you login before TCP/IP is fully working, this uses cached credentials when a client is using active directory to login (so basically a race condition).  You need to check if the TCP/IP is up and running. Not sure how to do this from a standard app. However for a service you can just make your service dependent on the TCP/IP service.

Comment: @RichardCritten Thank You very much for answer. After fast research I can't find appropriate service under Windows _Services_ manager. Can You give me some hints how to find it?

Comment: Probably the `workstation` service ... it's been quote a few years since I last look at this (GINA development for Windows XP)

Comment: "*You need to check if the TCP/IP is up and running. Not sure how to do this from a standard app*" - simply open a handle to the desired service with [`OpenService()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684330.aspx), and then call [`QueryServiceStatus()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684939.aspx) in a loop until the service is in the `SERVICE_RUNNING` state.

Comment: This might also have something to do with the Windows Firewall starting up.